# how to build Spring Restful support json data multi language?

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/category/all", method = {POST, GET})
public ListCategory all() {
    ListCategory response = new ListCategory();

    response.setListCategories(categoryDAO.selectAllCategory());
    response.setResponseStatus(1);
    //failedMessage = messageSource.getMessage("messages.customer.notActive", new Object[]{},Locale.getDefault());
    response.setResponseMessage(messageSource.getMessage("messages.agent.notAccessMenuAgent",
            new Object[]{},Locale.getDefault()));
    //activity Logging
    CommonMobileAgentUtil.activityLogging(response.getResponseStatus());

    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have the details you are looking for: http://www.ekiras.com/2016/01/springboot-internalization-and-i18n.html

Configuration:

> ```
> @Bean
> public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
>  SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
>  slr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US); // Set default Locale as US
>  return slr;
> }
>
> @Bean
> public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
>  ResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
>  source.setBasenames("i18n/messages");  // name of the resource bundle 
>  source.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
>  return source;
> }
> ```

Controller (note the Locale in the parameters):

> ```
> @RestController
> public class HomeController {
>
>    @Autowired
>    private MessageSource messageSource;
>
>    @RequestMapping("/msg")
>    public String msg(@RequestHeader("Accept-Language") Locale locale){
>       return messageSource.getMessage("msg",null,locale);
>    }
> }
> ```

Comment: i have 2 properties,, messages_en.properties and messages_id.propertiees. how able to do switching language?

Comment: How do you want to switch languages? You have a number of options. Read the [Web MVC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-localeresolver) docs around it. The most relevant would be the `LocaleChangeInterceptor`. Example of how to use that is here: https://justinrodenbostel.com/2014/05/13/part-4-internationalization-in-spring-boot/

Comment: i dont have a jsp or html file. i have a responseMessage in controller, how to read the responseMessage according to the language we choose in my android application?

Comment: How do you send the language to the server? Part of the header? Part of the URL query parameters? Whichever you choose you would want to setup an appropriate Resolver or Listener. The docs describe the options.

Comment: how do I explain every responseMessage in each controller?

Comment: That is an interesting question. I did some quick research and don't have anything around it. If I understand you correctly you are wanting to find a way for Spring to parse the JSON response and replace specific i18n tokens in the response with their language specific values. You might have to create your own `HandlerInterceptor` and process the response yourself. I would create a new question specifically around that to get some other feedback.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor